# How to get current loop number of ThreadGroup in jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I am using jmeter. I set Loop Count to 5 in ThreadGroup and number of Thread to 1. How can I get the current loop number so I can perform some operation in beanshell postprocessor?

Answer (score 10):

You can do it like `${__BeanShell(vars.getIteration();,)}` where:

- [__Beanshell](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__BeanShell) - JMeter function allowing execution of arbitrary [Beanshell script](http://www.beanshell.org/)
- `vars` - shorthand to [JMeterVariables](http://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html) class which holds current JMeter variables
- `getIteration()` method returns what you're looking for

See [How to use BeanShell: JMeter's favorite built-in component](http://blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell) guide for more information on Beanshell scripting in JMeter.