# Jmeter/Groovy: getting iteration number without reference to Beanshell

Tags: performance, groovy, jmeter, performance-testing

Basically [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30438294/how-to-get-current-loop-number-of-threadgroup-in-jmeter) in a slightly (but meaningfully!) different context. From within a Groovy script being run in jMeter (those are all the details I have at the moment), I need functionality to tell the script what iteration of the test it is currently on.

Comment: Why not use `vars.getIteration();`? Why it isn't a duplicate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 2 options:

1. Use [`vars.getIteration()`](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html#getIteration--) function
2. Since [JMeter 4.0](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/whats-new-in-jmeter-4) you can also get current [Thread Group](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) iteration as `${__jm__Thread Group__idx}`. From the Groovy script it would be [`vars.get('__jm__Thread Group__idx`)`](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html#get-java.lang.String-)